# Build fail due to ButterKnife crash when splitting APK

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, butterknife

We have a big project with many dependencies, several flavors and build types.

I tried to split APK according to [official instruction](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html). However, build failed. I tried the same steps on my side project and everything went well.

A stacktrace points that there is a problem with ButterKnife, but I can't get how to fix it.

```
:bankOK:compileBetaNewApiDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:bankOK:mergeBetaNewApiDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:bankOK:processBetaNewApiHdpiDebugManifest
:bankOK:processBetaNewApiHdpiDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bankOK:processBetaNewApiHdpiDebugResources'.
> Cannot invoke method replaceAll() on null object
```

And the exception is:

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bankOK:processBetaNewApiHdpiDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method replaceAll() on null object
    at butterknife.plugin.ButterKnifePlugin$_apply_closure1$_closure2$_closure3$_closure4.doCall(ButterKnifePlugin.groovy:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:590)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:571)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
```

Does anybody have any idea what the possible problem is?

Comment: post gradle also

Comment: Thank you. I already solved the problem, answer below. 

I don't think that our huge gradle file helps here, because it works well when we don't split apk and because I succesfully splitted my other projects, so it is not a simple problem that can be debugged without the whole project with same problem on-site.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/961) and [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/842) issues on Github, it looks like there are some problems with ButterKnife plugin.

Removing dependencies from plugin and turning it off solved the problem.

```
// commented:
// apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

Unfortunately, there is no other way to use ButterKnife in a library module (that is connected as `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`) except this plugin, so I removed it from library module and just left it in the main module as a usual dependency:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
```